# OpenLDAP search filter DN-Syntax error (34) Authentication failed

Tags: ldap, syntax-error, openldap

I am trying since days to configure the search filter for OpenLDAP connection with a tool that I am using.
But I always get the error message: DN-Syntax error (34) Authentication failed
My Searchfilter looks like this:

**Base DN**: `ou=myorganizationunit2,ou=myorganizationunit,o=myorganizationname,c=DE`

**User search filter**: `(&(|(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(objectClass=user)) (uid=#LDAP_LOGIN#)))`

What am I doing wrong?

Thankful for any help

Comment: The search filter looks wrong, you need to remove the space between conditions and the closing parenthesis: `(&(|(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(objectClass=user))(uid=#LDAP_LOGIN#))`. Also your base dn is missing domain components (like `...,dc=domain,dc=com`).

Comment: Thanks, I tried to follow your advice but still the same error message:

**Base DN**: ```ou=myorganizationunit2,ou=myorganizationunit,dc=myorganizationname,dc=DE```

Comment: Got the solution: 

The connection was password and not binding. Furthermore the used user value was wrong. It has to include the whole DN Base name.